# Find the number $|z_1|$ where $\left|\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers such that
>   $$\left|\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|=1$$
>   where $|z_2|\neq1$. Find $|z_1|$.

I could not understand in this if we are not given $z_2$ then how we find $z_1$

Comment: Maybe find $z_1$ in terms of $z_2$?

Comment: You can't find $z_1.$ You weren't asked to find $z_1,$ you just have to find $|z_1|.$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг answer is given as 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint - write it as:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
|z_1-2z_2|^2=|2-z_1 \bar z_2|^2 & \quad\iff\quad (z_1-2z_2)(\bar z_1-2 \bar z_2) = (2-z_1 \bar z_2)(2-\bar z_1 z_2) \\ 
& \quad\iff\quad |z_1|^2 - \cancel{2z_1\bar z_2}-\bcancel{2z_2 \bar z_1} + 4 |z_2|^2 = 4 - \bcancel{2\bar z_1 z_2} - \cancel{2 z_1 \bar z_2} +|z_1|^2|z_2|^2 \\
& \quad\iff\quad \left(|z_1|^2-4\right)\left(1-|z_2|^2\right)=0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $w=\dfrac{z_1}{2}$ thus
$$f(w)=\frac{w-2z_2}{1-w\bar{z_2}}$$
is a bilinear transformation that carry circle to circle which $|f|=1$, so every points $|w|=1$ goes to $|f|=1$ so $|z_1|=2$.

Answer (score 3):

WLOG $z_1-2z_2=e^{it}(2-z_1\overline{z_2})$

$\iff\dfrac{z_1}2=\dfrac{e^{it}+z_2}{1+e^{it}\overline{z_2}}$

Now $\left|\dfrac{e^{it}+z_2}{1+e^{it}\overline{z_2}}\right|^2=\dfrac{(\cos t+a)^2+(\sin t+b)^2}{(1+a\cos t+b\sin t)^2+(b\cos t-a\sin t)^2}=1$

Comment: Here $z_2=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real